# C# remote stream for file transfer does not read

Tags: c#, file, tcp, stream, streamwriter

i have written a little "Update Programm" to keep an .exe up to date for the rest of my dev team. It used to work fine, but suddenly it stopped working.

I already noticed the problem: my remote stream does not start to read.

```
        Uri patch = new Uri("http://********/*********/" + GetVersion().ToString() + ".exe");
        Int64 patchsize = PatchSize(patch);
        var CurrentPath = String.Format("{0}\\", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        Int64 IntSizeTotal = 0;
        Int64 IntRunning = 0;
        string strNextPatch = (version + ".exe");

        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            using (System.IO.Stream streamRemote = client.OpenRead(patch))
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream streamLocal = new FileStream(CurrentPath + strNextPatch, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    int intByteSize = 0;

                    byte[] byteBuffer = new Byte[IntSizeTotal];

                    while ((intByteSize = streamRemote.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        streamLocal.Write(byteBuffer, 0, intByteSize);

                        IntRunning += intByteSize;

                        double dIndex = (double)(IntRunning);
                        double dTotal = (double)byteBuffer.Length;
                        double dProgressPercentage = (dIndex / dTotal);
                        int intProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage * 100);

                        worker.ReportProgress(intProgressPercentage);
                    }
                    streamLocal.Close();
                }
                streamRemote.Close();
```

GetVersion() only returns the current version number of the current server version of the .exe.
The problem lies here:

```
while ((intByteSize = streamRemote.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
```

My streamRemote just does not return any bytes so this while clause is not filled.

Any advice for me?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you can remove the redundant Close() calls - that's what the using statements are for. You can also stack all your usings on top of each other and have you block at one level of indentation.

Comment: Thank you! I did this to get a little more 'overview' into my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is on the server. I'd run some checks:

- Has anything changed on the configuration of the web server that stops you from downloading executables?
- Are you connecting through a proxy?
- Can you manually get to the same URL (under the same user credentials of your application)?

Comment: Well, thanks for you help, but i already got the problem. 

                    byte[] byteBuffer = new Byte[IntSizeTotal];
had to be 

                    byte[] byteBuffer = new Byte[patchsize];
and now its working :)

Comment: Ok, thought it was an external problem as you said "It used to work fine, but suddenly it stopped working" :)